# Problema con función de Node.js y Express: No se obtiene respuesta esperada al insertar en MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy enfrentando un problema con una función en mi servidor Node.js construido con Express. La función en cuestión debería insertar datos en una base de datos MongoDB y devolver un mensaje de éxito, pero no estoy obteniendo la respuesta esperada.

```
  const createNews = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title, subtitle, description } = req.body;
    const fotoFileNewsPath = req.file?.path; 

    if (!title || !subtitle || !description || !fotoFileNewsPath) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Faltan datos requeridos' });
    }

    const nuevaNoticia = {
      title,
      subtitle,
      description,
      image: fotoFileNewsPath,
    };

    const newsCollection = dba.collection("news");
    const resultado = await newsCollection.insertOne(nuevaNoticia);

    if (resultado.insertedCount === 1) {
      console.log("Noticia creada con éxito.");
      return res.json({ message: 'Noticia creada con éxito.' });
    }
    return res.status(500).send();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).send();
  }
};
```

Después de ejecutar esta función, espero recibir un mensaje de éxito cuando la noticia se inserta correctamente en la base de datos. Sin embargo, la respuesta que obtengo es un código de estado 500 sin un cuerpo de respuesta.

¿Por qué podría estar recibiendo un código de estado 500 en lugar del mensaje de éxito después de una inserción exitosa?

¿Cómo puedo modificar esta función para obtener la respuesta esperada?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o sugerencia para solucionar este problema. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Veo que usas el driver de MongoDB directamente. ¿Podrías mostrar cómo lo instancias?. No es muy común ver que se use directamente, sino que se use algún gestor como Mongoose. Por otro lado, trata de hacer `console.log(resultado)`, tal vez la respuesta que esperas recibir no es la que realmente estás recibiendo, por lo que la condición para enviar el mensaje de éxito estaría fallando. Saludos